# Is WinDbg displaying the wrong opcode of [MOV r32,r/m32]?

Tags: x86, intel, windbg, disassembly, visual-studio-2019

I was patching the VS2019 16.2.3 linker located at
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\bin\Hostx86\x86\link.exe" in order to get rid of the Rich Signature as usual with WinDbg:10.0.17763.132 X86.

First find the only call of link!IMAGE::CbBuildProdidBlock inside link!IMAGE::BuildImage:

```
ModLoad: 00130000 00297000   link.exe
```

```
0:000> # call*link!IMAGE::CbBuildProdidBlock link!IMAGE::BuildImage
link!IMAGE::BuildImage+0xeac:
00176e28 e896830000      call    link!IMAGE::CbBuildProdidBlock (0017f1c3)
```

Then:

```
0:000> u 00176e28
link!IMAGE::BuildImage+0xeac:
00176e28 e896830000      call    link!IMAGE::CbBuildProdidBlock (0017f1c3)
00176e2d 8b8f90020000    mov     ecx,dword ptr [edi+290h]
00176e33 8b1518d42500    mov     edx,dword ptr [link!CbHdr (0025d418)]
00176e39 03c8            add     ecx,eax
00176e3b 898528faffff    mov     dword ptr [ebp-5D8h],eax
00176e41 8d8500faffff    lea     eax,[ebp-600h]
00176e47 898f94020000    mov     dword ptr [edi+294h],ecx
00176e4d 8bcf            mov     ecx,edi
```

So to change `add ecx,eax` to `nop` `nop` will do the trick.

Accidentally I found the line above `add ecx,eax` is

```
00176e33 8b1518d42500    mov     edx,dword ptr [link!CbHdr (0025d418)]
```

and its file offset is 00176e33 - 00130000 - (1000 - 400) = 46233.

However in both Notepad++ + HexEditor and VSCode + hexdump, it shows 8B 15 18 D4 **52** 00 not 8B 15 18 D4 **25** 00

```
00046230: 02 00 00 8B 15 18 D4 52 00 03 C8 89 85 28 FA FF
```

I tried to copy the file to anywhere else, or start WinDbg several times to ensure that's not caused by data error, still the same result.

Why WinDbg is displaying "8b1518d4**25**00" not "8B 15 18 D4 **52** 00" at 00176e33, do I have to know the Intel X86 Opcode and Instruction Reference thoroughly in order to solve this?

Comment: off-topic `66 90` is a 2-byte NOP, you don't need two separate `nop` instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes Had new knowledge learned!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `windbg` showing you the disassembly after fixups for runtime relocation have been applied?  It is 32-bit code so it can't use RIP-relative addressing.

That would explain some high bits of an absolute address in an instruction being different from in the file on disk.

The `0x25` byte is the 2nd-highest byte of the little-endian disp32 encoding of the `[link!CbHdr (0025d418)]` addressing mode in that `mov   edx, [disp32]` instruction.

Comment: Yes, I guess the fixups for runtime relocation have been applied, I used ```g $exentry``` to tell WinDbg goto the entrypoint of link.exe.